# AFNetworking 3.0 download background mode

Tags: afnetworking, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I use **AFNetworking** library 3.0 for download files. I created singleton for AFNetworking session but when my phone go to lockscreen session has been canceled. Also my project has accept "Background fetch mode"
What i am doing wrong? Thanks for help!
My code below:

```
-(void)downloadShowingProgress:(NSString *)url nameString:(NSString *)nameString indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    self.downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSURL *directoryURL = [fileManager URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [directoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@".fade"];
        NSError *error;
        if ([fileManager createDirectoryAtURL:documentsDirectoryURL withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]){
            NSLog(@"Create Sucess");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Create error: %@", error);
        }

        return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3",nameString]];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"** File downloaded to: %@", filePath);

    }];

    [self.downloadTask resume];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must be add backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier like that:

```c
-(void)downloadShowingProgress:(NSString *)url nameString:(NSString *)nameString indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"download-task"];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    self.downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {

        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        NSURL *directoryURL = [fileManager URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
        NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [directoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@".fade"];
        NSError *error;
        if ([fileManager createDirectoryAtURL:documentsDirectoryURL withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]){
            NSLog(@"Create Sucess");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"Create error: %@", error);
        }

        return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp3",nameString]];
    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"** File downloaded to: %@", filePath);

    }];

    [self.downloadTask resume];

}
```